# What are the n-dimensional matrix multiplication transpose rules?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume I have an n-dimensional matrix A of dimensions (A,B,C,...) and a n-dimensional matrix B of dimensions (X,Y,Z, ...). Does $(A*B)^T = B^T*A^T$ still?

Where the transpose operation is an arbitrary permutation of the dimensions.

Comment: And what is $*$?

Comment: Huh? “Arbitrary permutation of the dimensions”?

Comment: @TedShifrin The concept makes sense (see the [aperm](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/aperm) function in R). However the notation is of course nonsensical, and the relation would be wrong for (2D) matrices: $(AB)^T$ is not $B^TA^T$ for an arbitrary permutation (the identity is a permutation). I don't think the question is going anywhere, but I'm still curious.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Good point about the 2d example where the permutation is unchanged. What kind of options are there for matrix multiplication in n-d space? I assumed * is https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html

Comment: You may have a look at [this article](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/tensordot-explained-6673cfa5697f) about the Python (numpy) [tensordot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) function.